Sound to headphones instead of Android Auto
I have a Samsung A53 connected to my car via Android Auto. Everything works fine, but sometimes I need sound from my Phone to be forwarded not to car system, but to headphones connected via USB to my Samsung phone. How to achieve that?

I have not tried that with Android Auto.  However, if it's possible than the method is

Long press the Bluetooth Icon
Select the Car that it has connected to
Click on the Setup icon (gear wheel)
Unselect Audio

The flip method if the above is not achievable (for BT headphones only)

Long press the Bluetooth Icon
Select the headphone that it has connected to
Click on the Setup icon (gear wheel)
Select Audio

